# How to calculate the bullet origin of a barrel on a rotating turret

Tags: java, algorithm, math

**Problem**

I'd like to calculate the origin of a bullet which comes out of turret barrels which aren't at the center of the turret.

**Current Situation**

I have a turret with a center barrel which can shoot bullets from it. The turret is at the vector `location` and as a varying `angle`, i. e. it keeps rotating. In order to make the center turret shoot bullets from the end of the barrel I calculate the end of it like this:

```
    double speed = 1;
    double angle = turret.angle;
    
    // start at the end of the barrel
    double x = turret.location.x + Math.cos( angle) * turret.centerCannonLength;
    double y = turret.location.y + Math.sin( angle) * turret.centerCannonLength;

    // calculate angle and velocity of bullets
    double dx = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
    double dy = Math.sin(angle) * speed;
```

from that I can set the initial location and the velocity of the bullets with this:

```
    Bullet bullet = new Bullet();
    bullet.setLocation( x, y);
    bullet.setVelocity( dx, dy);
    bullet.setAngle( angle);
```

**Task**

Now I'd like to have 2 additional barrels from which the turret can fire. The barrels aren't in the center, they are offset left and right.

**Question**

How do I calculate the origin of the bullets from the left and right barrel?

Here's a demo screenshot:

[image]

The blue circle describes the rotation of the turret. The yellow parts are the turret and the center barrel. The red parts are the additional left and right barrels of which I'd like to calculate the bullet origin position.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, define the location of the origin in the turret's local coordinate space. The center barrel would be:

```
localX = turret.centerCannonLength
localY = 0
```

Then, find the current rotation matrix of the turret:

```
M = /  cos(angle)  -sin(angle)  \
    \  sin(angle)   cos(angle)  /
```

And multiply this matrix with the local position:

```
globalX = turret.location.x + cos(angle) * localX - sin(angle) * localY
globalY = turret.location.y + sin(angle) * localX + cos(angle) * localY
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. You got a typo in the last line, i. e. should be + cos( angle) according to the matrix.